# How to achieve a color gradient following the x-axes in the points of a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

I'm working with a ListPlot of several points.

I'd like to plot the points with a gradient of colors (for example, from blue to red) following their position in the x-axes.

For example:

```
x = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
y = {1,3,5,3,1,4,7,10,5,0,1};
data = Transpose@{x, y};
myplot = ListPlot[data]
```

That plots appears as:

[image]

I'd like to have a continuous change of the markers' colors, from blue tonalities in the left (near to x = 0) to red tonalities in the right (near x = 10).

What command should I use inside the ListPlot?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: See also a relevant example in the docs for `ListPlot`: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html#1706009447

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `ListPlot`, one easy way to go is to wrap the data points in `Style`:

```
ListPlot[
    Map[
        Style[#, Blend[{Blue, Red}, #[[1]] / 10.]]&,
        data
    ]
]
```

[image]